Error Handling with spring cloud stream kafka
I'm using Spring's `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka in my Spring Boot application, featuring a Spring Cloud function responsible for upsert operations. Upon successful execution, this function forwards the input message as output. The configuration for this function is outlined below:
      SPRING_CLOUD_FUNCTION_DEFINITION: upsertData

      SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_BINDINGS_upsertData-in-0_DESTINATION: UpsertDataEvent
      spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upsertData-in-0.group: upsert-data-event-group
      spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upsertDataGroup-in-0.content-type: application/json

      SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_BINDINGS_upsertData-out-0_DESTINATION: UpsertDataSuccessEvent
      spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upsertData-out-0.producer.partitionCount: 1
      spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upsertData-out-0.group: upsert-data-success-event-group
      spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upsertData-out-0.content-type: application/json

I've been tasked with meeting the following requirements from a client:

Deploy 12 instances of this application, each with 12 Kafka partitions assigned, one partition per consumer instance. This is straightforward to accomplish.
In case of a failure, route the input message to an error topic with the error message as a header. This can be implemented easily.
Implement a mechanism where, upon sending a message to the error topic (specific to the partition of the consumer where the error occurred), that particular consumer halts consumption until the error topic is cleared. However, the application's HTTP endpoint should remain operational, albeit with event consumption from the input topic paused.

I've provided my current implementation below. However, I'm unsure how to fulfil requirement 3:
@Component("upsertData")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyCloudFunction implements Function<Message<Data>, Data> {

    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Override
    public Data apply(Message<Data> message) {
        log.info("Upsert Data Message received: {}", message);
        Data requestPayload = message.getPayload();

        try {
            var searchResult = // Get Data Logic

            if (searchResult != null) {
                // Update Data Logic
            } else {
                // Create Data Logic
            }

            log.info("Upsert Data Event processed successfully");

            return requestPayload;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error processing message. Sending to error queue.", e);
            sendMessageToErrorTopic(e, requestPayload);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void sendMessageToErrorTopic(Exception e, Data requestPayload) {
        Message<Data> errorMessage =
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestPayload)
                .setHeader("error-reason", e)
                .build();
        streamBridge.send("UpsertDataFailureEvent", errorMessage);
    }

}



Do you want to pause the entire consumer? Or just the instance from where the error occurred? If it is the former, there is a way to pause the consumer today in Spring Cloud Stream. It gets tricky if you have to pause consumption from a single partition.

@sobychacko This is just the instance where the error occurs. I think I made it work via the code below but now the problem is how to resume where the error queue is cleaned up manually. In spring cloud function, I only have input and output channel but for error queue read I am having difficulties

